# A question about product and division of random variables

Tags: random-variable, bivariate

Taken three real continuous random variables $X,Y,Z$, non negative (to simplify the handling of the problem),
with respective pdf's $p_X , p_Y , p_Z$ .

Then if
$$
Z = XY\quad \left| {X,Y\;indep.} \right.
$$
[it is known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_of_the_product_of_two_random_variables) that
$$
p_{\,Z} (z)dz = dz\int_{x\, = \,0}^\infty  {p_{\,X} (x)p_{\,Y} (z/x)\frac{1}{x}dx}
  = dz\int_{y\, = \,0}^\infty  {p_{\,X} (z/y)p_{\,Y} (y)\frac{1}{y}dy}  \quad\tag{1}
$$

If instead we have
$$
X = Z/Y\quad \left| {Z,Y\;indep.} \right.
$$
then
$$
p_{\,X} (x)dx = dx\int_{y\, = \,0}^\infty  {p_{\,Z} (xy)p_{\,Y} (y)ydy}
  = dx\int_{z\, = \,0}^\infty  {p_{\,Z} (z)p_{\,Y} (z/x)\frac{z}{{x^2 }}dz} \quad \tag{2}
$$

I am aware that, if I take the $p_Z$  in (1) and "divide" it by $p_Y$ I won't get $p_X$, since $Z=XY$ and $Y$ are not independent,
rather I will get the distribution of
$$
X' = XY/Y'\quad \left| {\;Y,Y'\;i.i.d.} \right.
$$

That premised, coming back to
$$
Z = XY\quad \left| {X,Y\;indep.} \right.
$$
knowing $p_Z$ and $p_Y$ how can I recover $p_X$ ?

Comment: Take logarithms: your question is now about *deconvolution* of two variables.

Comment: @whuber. thanks that might be a way, but then the pdf's would get quite "complicated" ...

Comment: There's no help for that.  The formulas are actually *much* simpler for deconvolution because it corresponds to dividing one characteristic function by another.  I think the moral is that for this kind of operation, pdfs are to be avoided in favor of other representations of the distributions.

Comment: @whuber: I see .. being a multiplication, perhaps the Mellin /anti-Mellin (Meijer G) could work ?